# How to push CSS file though Http2?

Tags: asp.net, http2, server-push

I'm implementing Asp.net framework 4.6.1 project and I want to add HTTP2 server push for that project. Here I'm working with aspx.cs file and I used Html extension to push style-sheets as follows:

`<%: Html.PushPromiseStylesheet("~/content/styles/Tree.common.min.css") %>`

But this is not work for me. Is there is any other way to push css file via HTTP2 server push?

Answer (score 0):

PUSH_PROMISE method can be used to apply HTTP/2 server push because the server creates the PUSH_PROMISE frame to the response part of a normal browser- initiated stream. 
Response objects with the context of a request which has a HTTP connection is used to server push. In a server side under the **HTTP connection method** like Page_load method can be used to apply `Response.PUSHPROMISE` for push all the relevant scripts, styles and images without the client having to request each one explicitly.

```
 Response.PushPromise("direction/to/style-sheet");
```